# Java Server Faces and Content Security Policy?

Tags: jsf, web, content-security-policy

I would like to use [Content Security Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Security_Policy) for my JSF 2.1 based Web projects as I think it could improve protection against XSS attacks significantly.

Due to CSP's default behaviour to [block all inline JavaScript](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/content-security-policy/#inline-code-considered-harmful) it basically breaks JSF's

```
<f:ajax execute="input" render="output" />
```

functionality. This is because JSF generates lots of inline JavaScript code when using the above stated construct.

Does anybody know if there is a way to use CSP in JSF based projects which make use of *f:ajax* without the need to allow inline JS by using the following CSP directive:

```
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'
```

I know that manually placing all of the JavaScript in a separate file would be possible, but doing so I would be forced to do all the Ajax stuff manually.

Comment: You didn't mark the answer as accepted, so I'm assuming you didn't do it that way, if so how did you do it ?

Answer (score 4):

You could avoid using the `unsafe-inline` source-expression in order to whitelist inline `<script>`s, by utilizing *nonce* and/or *hash*  instead [[1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSP11/)]. Doing so would require:

- Inclusion of a `nonce` attribute in inline `<script>` elements, e.g.

  `<f:ajax ... pt:nonce="$placeHolder" />`

  (assuming that the `pt` prefix has been bound to the `http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough` namespace). The attribute's value could just be a placeholder within the view file, enabling you to replace it collectively in all trusted inline `<script>`s later on.
- Replacement (via a `Filter`, for instance) of the placeholder with a random value in each response and insertion of that value into the CSP HTTP Header and/or equivalent `<meta>` element, producing for example

  `<script ... nonce="126cfb...">` and

  `Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'; ... script-src 'self' 'nonce-126cfb...'`.

  Theoretically, produced *nonce-value*s should also be stored on the server, to avoid their reassignment in the near future, since they're supposed to be *unique*.
- Additionally or alternatively, insertion of each trusted inline `<script>` contents' *digest* into the CSP HTTP Header and/or equivalent `<meta>` element, alongside its respective *hash-algo*, such as

  `Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'sha256-126cfb...='`.

  *hash-value*s should too be regenerated while preparing each response, I guess, since `<script>`s are generally expected to change over time and with JSF you might not immediately notice when they do.