# h:commandLink and unsafe-inline

Tags: jsf, content-security-policy

If you look at this [Mkyong example](https://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-link-commandlink-and-outputlink-example/) of how `h:commandLink` is resolved, it looks like this.

```
//JSF
<h:commandLink action="#{user.goLoginPage}" value="Login page + Param ">
    <f:param name="username" value="mkyong" />
</h:commandLink>

//HTML output
<script type="text/javascript"
 src="/JavaServerFaces/faces/javax.faces.resource/jsf.js?ln=javax.faces&stage=Development">
</script>

<a href="#"
    onclick="mojarra.jsfcljs(document.getElementById('j_idt6'),
    {'j_idt6:j_idt20':'j_idt6:j_idt20','username':'mkyong'},'');
    return false">
    Login page + Param
</a>
```

The problem with this is that if you are enforcing `unsafe-inline` your browser will refuse to execute this.

I've been whitelisting inline scripts with the [nonce method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22593549/java-server-faces-and-content-security-policy).

Is there a way to allow the `h:commandLinks` to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is in HTML **no way** to perform a POST request using an `<a>` element. JSF in this context being just a HTML code generator can't do much about that.

You have 3 options:

1. Replace by `<h:commandButton>`.
2. Or, replace by `<h:link>`.
3. Or, replace by a custom component which initializes the script externally.

#### See also:

- [How to navigate in JSF? How to make URL reflect current page (and not previous one)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15521451/how-to-navigate-in-jsf-how-to-make-url-reflect-current-page-and-not-previous-o)
- [Semantics of "?faces-redirect=true" in <commandlink action=...> and why not use it everywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11242240/semantics-of-faces-redirect-true-in-commandlink-action-and-why-not-use/)