# content-security-policy header for a jsf, primefaces application

Tags: jsf, primefaces, content-security-policy

As JSF and Primefaces components result in inline scripts, it is difficult to configure the CSP header in its best configuration.

As [JSF by design provides XSS protection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7722159/csrf-xss-and-sql-injection-attack-prevention-in-jsf), is it okay to not use CSP at all or what shall be the best CSP value for a JSF+Primefaces application?

Also, there is not much discussion/sample-code available on the topic on Internet [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22593549/java-server-faces-and-content-security-policy)[[2]](https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?t=43356). Aren't JSF and Primefaces planning to provide easier implementation of CSP, as it is 'defense-in-depth', highly recommended header?

Comment: We will evaluate it for the next release: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/3505

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To enable it you may add the following context parameter to your web.xml:

```
<context-param>
<param-name>primefaces.CSP</param-name>
<param-value>true</param-value>
```

Comment: Do you have a reference to documentation? Versions this should work for? Etc

Comment: https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/8_0/#/core/contentsecuritypolicy